# Iterate over X dictionary items in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I iterate over only X number of dictionary items? I can do it using the following bulky way, but I am sure Python allows a more elegant way.

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5} 
x = 0
for key in d:
    if x == 3:
       break
    print key
    x += 1
```

Comment: what's the purpose of this?

Comment: `for key in d.keys()[:X]: ...`? If you are concerned about memory, you can also use `from itertools import islice` then `for key in islice(d, X):`

Comment: The ultimate purpose is to shuffle my dictionary every time and use only X items from it.

Comment: @sprogissd Google how to random sample something. That functionality is available in a library.

Comment: Just to note, depending upon the version of Python you're using, the keys might not be in the order you've defined.

Comment: @sprogissd You can't shuffle a dictionary and have no direct control over the order of keys in Python 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a random sample of `X` values from a dictionary you can use [**`random.sample`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) on the dictionary's keys:

```
from random import sample

d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5}

X = 3

for key in sample(d, X):
    print key, d[key]
```

And get output for example:

```
e 5
c 3
b 2
```